# Integral of reciprocal square root of $\operatorname{cosec}(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Is there a neat closed-form solution to the integral of $$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{a^2\csc^2(x)-b^2}}$$ for some constant $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Looks like one similar to an elliptic integral I was trying to solve some time ago, before I found out mine doesn't have a closed form solution in elementary functions.  I would expect this one has the same situation, but I don't have a list of elliptic integrals handy to check...

Comment: @abiessu This integral does have a closed form.

Comment: $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2\csc^2x-b^2}}dx=
-\frac1b \sinh^{-1} \frac {b \cot x}{\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)\csc^2x}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral has a closed form:
$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^{2}\csc\left(t\right)^{2}-b^{2}}}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{b}\ln\left(\frac{b\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\sqrt{\csc\left(x\right)^{2}a^{2}-b^{2}}}{b-a}\right)$$

Incidentally, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%201%2Fsqrt%28a%5E2%20csc%28x%29%5E2-b%5E2%29) also solves it but in a different way.

Comment: what substitutions have you made?

Comment: @user157226 $\csc(t)=w$ . So you just get polynomial (with square roots)